# Can we create new elements or make old elements using nuclear fusion and fission

Tags: nuclear-physics, fusion, elements

Is it possible to use nuclear fusion and fission to create new elements? For example, if you have a carbon dioxide molecule, break the bond between carbon and oxygen, and use nuclear fusion/fission to make a new element, or use those electrons, protons, and neutrons to make an element, bond it with another element, and maybe the new molecule be more useful than carbon dioxide. Not sure If I'm missing something here, because nuclear fission and fusion would solve the whole world's problems if it were really this easy. So there's probably a monetary cost, or a high-risk, or something else I'm missing.

Comment: We do it all the time, so yes.

Comment: I get the impression you have not done any basic background reading (a requirement on this site).  Have you read Wikipedia's pages on Nuclear Fission and Fusion ?  It's a good starting point starting point.

Comment: Could you edit the question so that the English is better? For example, a question should end with a question mark. You might want to look up the meanings of 'carbon dioxide' and 'atom' and edit your question accordingly. Otherwise your question is liable to be deleted for being of low quality and apparently low effort. Also, I agree with StephenG's comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operating a particle accelerator or a atomic research reactor is an incredibly expensive process. It would be enormously wasteful of resources and energy to "transmute" matter in this way. The products of the reactions would have almost zero value compared to the huge costs incurred in making them.

Comment: Medical isotope production is one place where it is quite viable. Examples include fission of U235 to get Mo99 and thus Tc99m, or the O18(p,n)F18 reaction for PET scans.

Comment: -1. The annual operating costs for a cyclotron in the ballpark of $70~\rm MeV$ are $\sim \$1$ million. That would be a lot for an ordinary person, but it's hardly "incredibly expensive" by the standards of a university or lab that may run such a device. And the radioisotopes that can be created this way are extremely valuable.

Comment: The other almost industrial application of transmutation (but without being a fusion or a fission) is the doping of silicon which is done in research reactors.
The production of medical radio elements (in very small quantities) or the doping of silicon only requires relatively short irradiation times, which justifies these applications.
Otherwise, indeed, the use of reactors or accelerators is very expensive.